# Enabling additional USARTS for STM32 in Arduino

Tags: arduino, stm32, uart

I am trying building a project that requires me to use 6 UART connections. For this I have chosen the STM32F030CCT6 MCU, which supports 6 USARTs. I have gotten all 6 to work in the STM CubeIDE, but have decided to switch over to the Arduino IDE because I would like to use a few libraries.
In Arduino, I am using the latest Arduino_Core_STM32 api.

The api doesnt specify the suport for this exact chip, but it lists supports the STM32F030C8T6 chip, which for all intents is the same, with the only difference that it supports only 3 USARTS. I have tried using both HardwareSerial and SoftwareSerial libraries to add uarts, but when I add more then 2 UARTS the code compiles, uploads and executes until the first UART and then just "hangs" until I reset the chip.

My question is if I can somehow modify the library/get a different library that supports all 6 USARTS of this chip.
Alternativly, is it possible to use the working code generated in MXCube in Arduino and use the USART that way?
Or is this just a problem with Arduino_Core_STM32?

[used settings to program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Mh0.png)

code:

```
#include <EthernetENC.h>
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


HardwareSerial mySerial1(PA5,PA4); // compiles, can also use (USART1)
HardwareSerial mySerial2(PB11,PB10); // compiles, can also use (USART2)
HardwareSerial mySerial3(PA10,PA9); // compiles


void setup() {

    pinMode(PB15, OUTPUT);  //CP WRITE 34
    digitalWrite(PB15, LOW); 
}

void loop() {

 digitalWrite(PB15, HIGH); 
delay(500);
 digitalWrite(PB15, LOW); 
 delay(500);
   mySerial1.begin(9600);
  mySerial1.println("Hello, world?");
   mySerial1.end();

     mySerial2.begin(9600);
mySerial2.println("Hello, world2?");
   mySerial2.end();
   
     mySerial3.begin(9600);
mySerial3.println("Hello, world3?");
   mySerial3.end();
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/main/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L51 It should be all available. Unless you've got wrong "product line" other than STM32F030xC (only this one has 6 USARTs)

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you can't place an Arduino library into STM32CubeIDE project? Like yeah, you'll probably need to drag a pair of files into some folder of cube workspace, but it should make the whole thing much easier to develop. And you can easily include STM libraries as well for the finest control of the things when you need it (and cube mx generator integration). Not even speaking of ArduinoIDE lacking a lot of tools for more complex projects. So, are you sure you have to use ArduinoIDE for something that looks like it would be better in CubeIDE?

Comment: STM32F030CCT is not supported by the STM32duino Arduino Core yet, the variants folder only contains an empty template for the F030CCT. In order to support it, you need to fork the Arduino Core and [add a variant](https://github.com/stm32duino/wiki/wiki/Add-a-new-variant-%28board%29) and uses your fork version (and do a pull request to add your variant to the next release of the Arduino Core).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone for the insight, learned a lot of new things.

I managed to get all 6 USARTS to work by creating a new board variant.
The port map files were already present for this board (and many others )in the
AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\STMicroelectronics\hardware\stm32\2.3.0\variants folder.

I just edited the boards.txt file to add the F030CCT folder and created a .ld file in MX cube and added it to the folder. The board now behaves like it should and all the pins and functions work great.

I just changed the top part of the code to:

```
HardwareSerial SerialX(USART1);
HardwareSerial SerialY(USART2);
HardwareSerial Serialz(USART3);
HardwareSerial SerialX2(USART4);
HardwareSerial SerialY2(USART5);
HardwareSerial Serialz2(USART6);
```